# On click fade in another div using raphael js

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am using raphaeljs to draw a map of a building. I want to create popups for various rooms.

How can I use a click handler for a raphaeljs element to `fadeIn` another div?

```
t1.click(function(event) {
    alert("T1");
    $('#fademe').fadeIn(); // this does not work
});
```

I have found this way to [create a jQuery object out of a Raphaeljs object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630265/how-do-i-apply-css-styles-to-raphael-js-objects-using-jquery), but can't get it work:

```
var $jQueryObject = $(raphaelObject.node);
```

Any help appreciated. Using the demo below, you will find "T1" at the corner at the left side.

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/kjekupo0/28/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't loaded jquery. You don't need to create a jquery object from a Raph one, unless I'm misunderstanding what you want to manipulate.

Just remember to load it first, eg

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/kjekupo0/29/)